# Struggling with ggplot formatting on X/Y axis and a line drawn across a graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to format my graph to drop the time stamp and just have the month and year on both axis but struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong.  There's a poly drawn over the graph which I'd rather didn't have a border on all three sides and would like to draw a black diagonal line over the the poly (1:1 x/y) like the poly, but just to tart it up a bit.  Anyone able to help?

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Update_Date, y = Milestone_Finish_Date, group = Series)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Series), show.legend = TRUE, lwd = 1) +  # Set show.legend to FALSE
  geom_point(size = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +  # Set show.legend to FALSE
  geom_polygon(data = data.frame(
    x = c(min(data$Update_Date), max(data$Update_Date), max(data$Update_Date), min(data$Update_Date)),
    y = c(min(data$Milestone_Finish_Date), min(data$Milestone_Finish_Date), max(data$Milestone_Finish_Date), min(data$Milestone_Finish_Date)),
    Series = rep("", 1)
  ), aes(x = x, y = y, fill = Series), alpha = 1, color = "grey", lwd = 1.1, show.legend = FALSE) +  # Add a black border line
 
  labs(title = "Milestone Trend Analysis Chart",
       x = "Update Date",
       y = "Milestone Finish Date") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +  # Remove legend title
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "Series")) +  # Replace "Series" with your desired legend title
  scale_fill_manual(values = "white") +  # Set the polygon fill color to white
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%M/%Y")
```

What I'd like it to look like!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this as an annotation rather than a geom layer. You could use a `ribbon` with a ymin of `-Inf` and then draw a line annotation:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = Update_Date, y = Milestone_Finish_Date, group = Series)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Series), show.legend = TRUE, lwd = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 1, show.legend = FALSE) + 
  annotate('ribbon', ymin = c(-Inf, -Inf), ymax = c(1, 9), 
           x = as.Date(c('2018-12-01', '2019-06-02')), fill = 'white') +
  annotate('line', x = as.Date(c('2018-12-01', '2019-06-02')), y = c(1, 9),
           color = 'black', linewidth = 1) +
  labs(title = "Milestone Trend Analysis Chart",
       x = "Update Date",
       y = "Milestone Finish Date") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "top", aspect.ratio = 1) + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m/%Y", date_breaks = 'month') +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = as.Date(c('2018-12-01', '2019-06-01')))
```

[image]

---

**Data used - inferred from picture in question**

```r
data <- data.frame(
  Update_Date = rep(seq(as.Date('2018-12-01'),
                        by = 'month', length.out = 7), times = 5),
  Series = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 7),
  Milestone_Finish_Date = c(rep(c("2019-01-01"), 11),
                            c('2019-04-01', '2019-04-10', '2019-05-10'),
                            '2019-05-20', '2019-05-20', '2019-05-25',
                            rep('2019-05-10', 4), '2019-05-25', '2019-05-25',
                            rep('2019-05-30', 5), '2019-06-10', '2019-06-10',
                            '2019-06-15', rep('2019-06-10', 4))
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for this, using your dataset it works - are you able to help with the import from powerbi? I'm not sure of the syntax.  I'm using data = dataset but that does not import the data as dates and therefore seems to fail.

Comment: I've updated to this, data <- data.frame(as.Date(Milestone_Finish_Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), Series, as.Date(Update_Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) - I'm sure I'm doing something stupid.

Comment: basically the error I get is object 'Milestone_Finish_Date' not found

Comment: What format is your data in when you import it? Is it a data frame?

Comment: Powerbi brings it in like this: # The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script: 

# dataset <- data.frame(Milestone_Finish_Date, Series, Update_Date) - so yes a data frame.  However, if I just go data = dataset (as I had been previously) I get the following error: Error Message:
R script error.
Error in `geom_line()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
â„¹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error:
! object 'Milestone_Finish_Date' not found

Comment: with your code, it works fine, so yes, technically a data frame, but it's not pulling the data in correctly.  My original code is fine, but has the issues corrected in this! :)

Comment: I can't really say without a reproducible example Tim. If you type `names(data)` into the console, do you get the correct names?

Comment: Well Allan, this is taking me down a rabbit hole.  Happy to send you the file, it's all mocked up data.  I've used data = dataset and if I modify your code to ggplot(data, aes(x = as.Date(data$Update_Date), y = data$Milestone_Finish_Date, group = Series)) that works fine for the X.  When I add the exact same code to the y (modifying to as.Date(data$Milestone_Finish_Date)) it exclaims it can't do that as it's not a date.  I've checked the data in PowerBI and they're all dates.  I've even duplicated the Update_Data and renamed it as the Milestone_Finish_Date data and it won't convert it to dates